# AutoFill fields in Laravel Backpack editEntity view

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Yoo everybody,
I am using laravel backpack and I have a field in a table that I put some data as a json in it:

```
    $rules['checkin'] = $request->checkin;
    $rules['checkout'] = $request->checkout;
    $rules['cancellation_policy'] = $request->cancellation_policy;

    $request->merge(['rules' => json_encode($rules)]);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to inject the data into edit form and auto-fill the fields. If this is a normal controller I get the data and decode it and then send it to view with other variables but in this case, I need help.

Comment: What have you tried to do in outputting the data in the edit form? and how does the data contained in the `$request` object look like

Comment: I recommend you create a new field type for your custom table - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type

Comment: You’ll then be able to use that custom field type like any other field, and even reuse it for other entities that might use it. Hope it helps!